# Max possible views on a custom list

Tags: list-view

I'm creating a custom list which needs 70 differents views on it (one for each users, this number may be bigger in the futur).
I know there was a 50 views limit in SP2007 (you could have more, but no way to access them in the interface), does that limit was fixed in SP2010 ? (no access to sharepoint atm to check by myself)
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it is wiser to create a view with a filter such as "[Created by] = [Me]"?

I find it really hard to believe that each user requires a unique view....

Answer (score 0):

70 * Pages with a Data View Web Parts will get around any limitations of the number of views you can have in a drop down. Just create a jumplist to access them all.

Answer (score 0):

Limit is still 50 in SP2010. Users can select from 50+ views in the Current View drop-down but when editing the view in web parts you are limited to the first 50 views created.

[Not all views being displayed in my web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79592/not-all-views-being-displayed-in-my-web-part)