# Not all views being displayed in my web part

Tags: list, web-part, list-view

Issue: Not all views being displayed in my web part. When selecting a view in my web part it only shows 30 views. How do I get it to show all views created for a list if there is more then 30?

Answer (score 1):

There was a not so documented limit of 50 views in WSS3/2007 that would be displayed in the list drop down on the list view web parts. This might still be the case (and still not entirely documented). I've never run into circumstances that needed that many views on a list. I believe you can rename the views to start with 1 or A so that these bubble to the top in the web part drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the views will not help move them to the top.  The problem appears to be a unique ID number assigned to each view as it is created.  Once you hit the max, no new views appear in the dropdown view selector.  I have tried to use designer to modify the view ID number, but that did not work or I did not find it in all places.  My work around for this bug is to re-use one of the first views created.  You can modify the parameters, rename it, add it to the webpart using the selector.  Once it is saved in your webpart, reuse it again and again to update all webparts/pages where you display those views.  In the end, I always put the view back to its original state.  Hope this helps!